# The harmonic conjugate of $\frac{1-|z|^2}{|a-z|^2}$ for some $a$.

Tags: complex-analysis

As an voluntary exercise in our complex analysis textbook, we had:

> Find the harmonic conjugate of
>   $$f_a(z) = \frac{1-|z|^2}{|a-z|^2}$$
>   for any $a \in \mathbb C$ with $|a| < 1$.

I really cannot solve it. If I expand it in terms of its imaginary and real parts, then set up the differential equation through Cauchy-Riemann, I get an monstrous integral, that I am not  able to do, nor is the **CAS** tools I've used.

I'm not aware of any smarter way to do this, apart from bruteforcing it, which I haven't had any success with either.

And: in general, what do I do when I need to find harmonic conjugates that I can't do by solving Cauchy-Riemann? What are the other techniques?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
u_\xi(z)
&=
\frac{1-|z|^2}{|\xi-z|^2} \\
&=
\dfrac12\frac{2\xi\bar{\xi}-2|z|^2}{|\xi-z|^2} \\
&=
\dfrac12\frac{(\xi\bar{\xi}+\bar{\xi}z -\xi\bar{z}-z\bar{z}) + (\xi\bar{\xi}-\bar{\xi}z +\xi\bar{z}-z\bar{z})}{(\xi-z)(\bar{\xi}-\bar{z})} \\
&=
\dfrac12\left(\frac{(\xi+z)(\bar{\xi}-\bar{z})}{(\xi-z)(\bar{\xi}-\bar{z})}+\frac{(\xi-z)(\bar{\xi}+\bar{z})}{(\xi-z)(\bar{\xi}-\bar{z})}\right) \\
&=
\dfrac12\left(\frac{\xi+z}{\xi-z}+\frac{\overline{\xi+z}}{\overline{\xi-z}} \right)\\
&=
\dfrac12{\bf Re\,}\dfrac{\xi+z}{\xi-z}.
\end{align}
then the harmonic conjugate of it is $v_\xi(z)=\dfrac12{\bf Im\,}\dfrac{\xi+z}{\xi-z}$.

Comment: This isn't real, is it? Is it missing an absolute value sign?

Comment: Oh, I see now..

Comment: Okay, this makes more sense. So, it appears you assume $|\xi| = 1$, right? What in the case with $|\xi| < 1$? What can be said there?

Comment: The hint says there is some smart way to find the harmonic conjugate for $|\xi| \leq 1$ by only having the harmonic conjugate of it when $|\xi| = 1$. I tried to divide out $|\xi|^2$ in both sides of the fraction, but it leaves $1/\xi^2$, which doesn't help me much, because I can't factor it out.

Comment: I think with $\xi=\dfrac{a}{|a|}$ then $\dfrac12{\bf Im\,}\dfrac{a+z}{a-z}$ is harmonic conjugate of $\dfrac12{\bf Re\,}\dfrac{a+z}{a-z}$.

Comment: But, like, the case of general $|a| < 1$.